# Convert from unicode in jsp for JSON's eval function

Tags: json, jsp, unicode

Im getting a string (simplified) from the backend that should be :

```
{ "menu": "Reallocate:"}
```

However it comes to jsp as:

```
{ &amp;#034;menu&amp;#034;: &amp;#034;Reallocate:&amp;#034;}
```

and i cannot pass this to the:

```
var data=eval("(" + src + ")");
```

as it just doesn't like it.. How can i convert this usable format?

I know that:

```
src = '{ "menu": "Reallocate:"}';
var data=eval("(" + src + ")");
```

works.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this with:

```
src = '{ "menu": "Reallocate:"}';
fname = fname.replace(/&#034;/g,'"');   
document.getElementById("testout").value = fname;
```

you can add other bits to replace other things too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could decode it before passing to eval. The Prototype Javascript library has built-in functions in the string class for doing it: http://prototypejs.org/api/string/unescapeHTML